# WPF's application wide styles in Windows Forms context

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

We migrate from WinForms to WPF... slowly =)

No we use WPF User Controls with ElementHost.

Is it possible to define application wide resources in this context? In pure WPF Application.Resources stands for it. But there's no WPF App when integrating with WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WPF application object even if your project is a WinForms one with a few separate WPF forms or controls. The object won't be precreated for you, but if you manually create it, simply by `new App()` (or even without a derived class, `new System.Windows.Application()`), everything in your project will see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx) and add it to the Resources of your UserControls. That way you just have to change your Styles in one location.

Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

and add it to your UserControl using [MergedDictionarys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

or just add it to the Control's Resources like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```